# Multiplication and Division of elements in a numpy array gives integer results

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2,1,-1,8],
         [-3,-1,2,-11],
         [-2,1,2,-3]])

B =  A[1]+A[0]* (-A[1][0]/A[0][0])
print(B) #B =[ 0.   0.5  0.5  1. ]
A[1] = A[1]+A[0]* (-A[1][0]/A[0][0])
print(A[1]) #A[1] = [0 0 0 1]
```

How does the above situation happen, and what can I do about it?

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: What is your question ? questions seeking debugging help should include desired behavior and an example of input and desired output.

Comment: `A` is dtype integer.  Assigning float values to such an array truncates them.  Try starting with a float dtype array (e.g. A = ...([[2., 1, ...]...`)

Comment: Really the title of this question should be edited to make sense.

Comment: @AGNGazer Took a stab at it.  The edited title makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `dtype=float` in main array. Your array is integer by default.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2,1,-1,8],
         [-3,-1,2,-11],
         [-2,1,2,-3]], dtype=float)
B =  A[1] + (A[0]*(-A[1,0]/A[0,0]))
print(B)
A[1] = A[1] + (A[0]*(-A[1,0]/A[0,0]))
print(A[1])
#Output:
#[ 0.   0.5  0.5  1. ]
#[ 0.   0.5  0.5  1. ]
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer  to use proper 2d array indexing , `A[0, 1]`?